# R, i have obtained the kmeans solution mathematically, but i am unable to plot the data

Tags: r

i have an excel file containing 700+ data points of power output, i need to create cluster of this information, i have used kmeans and got the mathematical solution for it but am unable to plot the result into some kind of a graph.

i tried using ggplot but am still unable to get any result.

i have tried examples of iris,etc and they work perfectly fine, but not when i use my database.

i am new to the software so don't know much, can someone please suggest something

Comment: Give example code in your question so we can see what you are doing. Also, this is R and not RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

1. You really should look at your code and give us a reproducible answer, you get out of your post what you put into it.
2. If you're new to software development you need to understand the basics before you can master complex tasks (I consider data mining and data visualizations a fairly detailed and complex task).
3. You need to either select 2 dimensions of your data set or do some type of data mining algorithm such as `PCA` or `TSNE` to reduce your data into geometrically interpretable dimensions so you can visualize your clusters as your third dimension or fourth. The following is a snippet of what Ive done in the past to handle this.

   `The following is an example of a 2d data scatter plot with the third dimension as cluster color`

   `ggplot()+geom_point(data=yourData, aes(x=dim1, y=dim2, color=cluster))`

Comment: Fyi, for block code, indent 4 spaces and don't use backticks. If it's under a bullet or something, you'll have to indent more.